# Cloud Code object.save() results in 'object not found' with very strange PUT command

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-server

#### Issue Description

I have a simple Cloud Code command to create or update an object.  If there is NO objectId passed in, the routine creates a new object and returns the objectId.  If the objectId exists in the parameter list, it fetches the object and updates the parameters accordingly.

The routine works for new objects fine.

The `object.save()` is failing when I try to update an object, despite the `object.fetch()` sub-routine working.

> error: code=101, message=Object not found.

Verbose server logs indicate a very strange `PUT` command...

> PUT /parse/classes/Receipt/[object%20Object]

what I would expect to see is

> PUT /parse/classes/Receipt/GJaXcf7fLD

Object ACL is public r+w

**Why is the `object.save()` not working with a valid objectId?**

_

**Cloud Code**

```
Parse.Cloud.define("uploadReceipt", function(request,response) {
    var Receipt = Parse.Object.extend("Receipt");
    var receipt = new Receipt();

    // passed in parameters are ['property' : ['type' : t, 'value' : v]]
    var dict = request.params;
    var objectIdDict = dict["objectId"];
    console.log("Object Dict: " + objectIdDict);
    Parse.Promise.as().then(function() {
        // if we already have an objectId we are UPDATING
        // Need to FETCH first
        if (objectIdDict != undefined) {
            console.log("Searching for ID: " + objectIdDict["value"]);
            receipt.set("objectId",objectIdDict["value"]);
            return receipt.fetch();
        }
        else {
            console.log("NEW RECEIPT");
            return Parse.Promise.as(receipt);
        }

    }).then(function(receipt) {
        console.log("Receipt: " + receipt.id);
        // copy over the keys from our passed in parameters to the object
        for (var key in dict) {
            //console.log("Key: " + key + "   Value: " + dict[key]["value"]);
            if (dict[key]["type"] == "Raw") {
                console.log("Key: " + key + "   Value: " + dict[key]["value"]);
                receipt.set(key,dict[key]["value"]);
            }
            else if (dict[key]["type"] == "Date" && key != "updatedAt") {
                console.log("Key: " + key + "   Value: " + dict[key]["value"]);
                var time = dict[key]["value"] * 1000;   // milliseconds
                receipt.set(key,new Date(time));
            }
            else {
                // object type
                var Obj = Parse.Object.extend(dict[key]["type"]);
                var newObj = new Obj();
                newObj.id = dict[key]["value"];
                receipt.set(key,newObj);
            }
        }

        // make sure our user is set
        receipt.set("user",request.user);

        // adjust the status because it has now been uploaded
        receipt.set("status",RECEIPT_SUBMITTED);

        console.log("Prior to save");
        return receipt.save();

    }).then(function(receipt) {
        console.log("Finished");
        response.success({"status":receipt.get("status"),"objectId":receipt.id});

    },function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        response.error(error);
    });
});
```

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Call the cloud code from iOS SDK with data for a new object
2. Notice that the command works and a new object is added to the database
3. Call the command again with updated information
4. Notice that the command fails with **object not found**

#### Expected Results

Object should be updated accordingly

#### Actual Outcome

> error: code=101, message=Object not found.

#### Environment Setup

- **Server**

  - parse-server version: 2.2.12
  - Operating System:     Mac OS X 10.11.5
  - Hardware:                  MacBook Pro 2010
  - Localhost or remote server? Localhost
  - Javascript:                 Parse/js1.8.5
  - NodeJS                      5.10.1
- **Database**

  - MongoDB version:  3.2.4
  - Hardware:         MacBook Pro 2010
  - Localhost or remote server? Localhost

#### Logs/Trace

**Storing NEW object returns**

```
verbose: POST /parse/classes/Receipt { 'user-agent': 'node-XMLHttpRequest, Parse/js1.8.5 (NodeJS 5.10.1)',
  accept: '*/*',
  'content-type': 'text/plain',
  host: 'localhost:1337',
  'content-length': '471',
  connection: 'close' } {
  "date": {
    "__type": "Date",
    "iso": "2016-06-19T00:30:37.492Z"
  },
  "category": {
    "__type": "Pointer",
    "className": "Category",
    "objectId": "XZ1bSHtZBY"
  },
  "status": 0,
  "amount": 61.45,
  "notes": "Hopefully this works well",
  "gui_status": -1,
  "currency": "USD",
  "user": {
    "__type": "Pointer",
    "className": "_User",
    "objectId": "vL4ih9BAX8"
  }
}
verbose: {
  "status": 201,
  "response": {
    "objectId": "GJaXcf7fLD",
    "createdAt": "2016-06-19T00:30:57.092Z"
  },
  "location": "http://localhost:1337/parse/classes/Receipt/GJaXcf7fLD"
}
Finished
verbose: {
  "response": {
    "result": {
      "status": 0,
      "objectId": "GJaXcf7fLD"
    }
  }
}
```

**Attempt to Update object returns**

```
verbose: PUT /parse/classes/Receipt/[object%20Object] { 'user-agent': 'node-XMLHttpRequest, Parse/js1.8.5 (NodeJS 5.10.1)',
  accept: '*/*',
  'content-type': 'text/plain',
  host: 'localhost:1337',
  'content-length': '473',
  connection: 'close' } {
  "category": {
    "__type": "Pointer",
    "className": "Category",
    "objectId": "XZ1bSHtZBY"
  },
  "status": 0,
  "amount": 5.47,
  "notes": "How about now",
  "gui_status": 0,
  "date": {
    "__type": "Date",
    "iso": "2016-06-19T00:12:25.788Z"
  },
  "currency": "USD",
  "user": {
    "__type": "Pointer",
    "className": "_User",
    "objectId": "vL4ih9BAX8"
  }
}
verbose: error: code=101, message=Object not found.
ParseError { code: 101, message: 'Object not found.' }
verbose: error: code=141, code=101, message=Object not found.
```

Comment: One thing I just noticed... when I am creating an object, the final save results in a POST, when I am editing an object it is a PUT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out thanks to some help from the parse-server community and GitHub user [flovilmart](http://github.com/flovilmart)

In the case of 'updating' an object, I was including a dictionary entry for the Receipt. This was successfully retrieving the Receipt that I wanted to update.

However, the issue was that once I pulled in the receipt object and was iterating through my dictionary of properties to update... I ran into the Receipt object information again. Thus I was trying to add a property of Receipt pointer to my Receipt with the pointer being itself! Ugh.

The very last else clause needed a condition on it to NOT include the pointer to the Receipt (itself)

```
  for (var key in dict) {
    if 
    ....
    else if (dict[key]["type"] != "Receipt"){
      // object type, but don't include ourself!  (the Receipt)
      var Obj = Parse.Object.extend(dict[key]["type"]);
      var newObj = new Obj();
      newObj.set("objectId",dict[key]["value"]);
      receipt.set(key,newObj);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Always a kick to offer a bounty and then answer the question yourself a couple hours later.  Oh well...